# I'm getting Import Error: No Module Named ecommerce.shipping in Python

Tags: python, import, module, importerror, traceback

***`I'm trying to import the "shipping" module in "try.py" but I'm getting this error.`***

```
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "try.py", line 1, in <module>
    from ecommerce.shipping import calc_shipping
ImportError: No module named ecommerce.shipping
```

What do you think is the problem?
here is the image of my project structure
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/F8L31.png

Comment: Are you running this script in the ecommerce folder?  If so,  try ```from .shipping import calc_shipping```

Comment: now I'm getting this: ValueError: Attempted relative import in non-package
does it mean, python can't see that ecommerce is not a package?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's inside the same directory as the script you can import it directly like this:

```
from shipping import calc_shipping
```

Comment: Thanks, It works
so, I wonder why it gives a warning. 
unresolved import 'shipping'Python(unresolved-import)

Comment: can you share the structure of shipping.py?

Comment: I shared an image of the whole structure in the Question.
For the shipping file I just have a simple function like this:

def calc_shipping():
    print("This is a Shipping Module")

Comment: Not Sure, because I am not getting any type of warning using the same structure

Answer (score 1):

Your code should

```
from .shipping import calc_shipping
```

The module is inside the same app so you have to type the code as above with a " . "   The dot refers to the files in the same app.

Comment: It give this: ValueError: Attempted relative import in non-package

Answer (score 0):

On such scenarios always check following things:

1. if the module has init, in other words if its a python module
2. check if its accessible from parent dir, in this example basics.

```
from .shipping import calc_shipping
```

Try this